# toString() method for Queue class

Tags: java, queue

Just a simple question, if I created a `Queue` class and initialized this

```
Queue queue = new Queue(5)
```

In the main method, and then enqueued and dequeued accordingly,

with the following instance variables, and `toString()` method:

```
 private int maxSize;
 private Planes[] queArray; 
 private int front;
 private int rear;
 private int nItems;

 public String toString()
 {
   String result = "[";
   for(int i = 0; i <= rear; i++)
   {
     result += " " + queArray[i];

     if(i <= rear - 1)
       result += ",";
   }
   result += " ]";
   return result;
 }//toString`
```

What variable do I stop at in the `for` loop:

`for(int i = 0; i <= rear; i++)`,

Right now I have it at `rear`, which doesn't seem to work how I want it to, and I know it's not `nItems`, or `maxSize` because that will print the entire `queue`, including the empty slots, and I just want the updated `queue`. 
I know for a `Stack`, you only print up to the `top` variable, but I'm more confused for the `Queue` class.

These are my `enqueue` and `dequeue` methods:

```
 public void enqueue(Plane name)
 {
   if(rear == maxSize-1)
   {
     rear = -1;
   }
   rear++;
   queArray[rear] = name;
   nItems++;
 }

 public Plane dequeue()
 {
   Plane temp = queArray[front];
   front++;
   if(front == maxSize)
   {
     front = 0;
   }
   nItems--;
   return temp;
 }
```

Comment: Can you share you enqueue and dequeue methods?

Comment: Do not concatenate strings in a loop. Use `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do queue and deque you should manipulate a variable inside the class. So in the beginning it will be equal to 0. After each queue or dequeue accordingly you will ++ or -- it.

Then this is the variable you use in toString to define end boundary for the loop. To use it anywhere in the class like this it should be an instance variable too.

edit:
After the code you added, seems like it should be `nitems`